# The logo doesn't appear properly in the letter

Tags: fancyhdr, letters, letterhead

I want to have the college logo at the center (in the header) followed by the college name, then a horizontal line , then the letter content.

But My Logo is half cut:

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{headheight = 275pt}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.70, keepaspectratio=true]{pecemblem.pdf}}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=0.5in, keepaspectratio=true]{pecemblem.pdf}}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}%
    \begin{letter}{}%
        \opening{Dear Some Name,}
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{letter}%
\end{document}%
```

The output I get is:

[image]

Comment: Adjust the head height`\geometry{headheight = 5pt}` or rescale the figure would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the logo to be centered you have to use `\fancyhead[C]`. If you substitute `C` with `R` you'll have it at the right and with `L` you'll have it at the left.

Also, play a little with `headheight` and with the `scale` options in `\includegraphics` to obtain the optimal result.

For example, with the following MWE and `pecemblem.png` downloaded from http://www.pec.edu/images/pecemblem.png

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{headheight=75pt,top=140pt}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{pecemblem}}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{pecemblem}}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}%
    \begin{letter}{}%
        \opening{Dear Some Name,}
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{letter}%
\end{document}%
```

I get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the space at the top and the page and the space for the heading within that space.  So put

```
\geometry{head=1in,top=2in}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=1in]{pecemblem.pdf}}}
```

There is a [very well written manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) in the `geometry` package that explains this (on p.3)

This picture shows all the different settings:[image]